# NodeJS proxy not working as intended

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, request, salesforce

The current route of the request originates on localhost:3001, goes through a proxy running on that same localhost at localhost:3001/proxy, where the request is then routed to the Salesforce instance. The proxy is made using ExpressJS and the client side app is made using AngularJS. Note: I did remember to tag my security token at the end of my password (Salesforce API requirement), although when using cURL, this doesn't seem to be necessary. Here are a series of HTTP traces that will hopefully provide some clues:

**HTTP Request Log from Angular.JS App:**

```
POST /proxy HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 234
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-User-Agent: salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/v29.0
Origin: http://localhost:3001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
SalesforceProxy-Endpoint: https://uniquename.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: liveagent_oref=; liveagent_ptid=3c69c2f9-139d-4439-ba6c-fd8d9dcae101; liveagent_vc=5
grant_type=password&client_id=3MVGxyzxyzxyzxyz&client_secret=99889988&username=first.last%40email.com&password=pswdwACYodaYfHs

400 Bad Request
Object {error_description: "grant type not supported", error: "unsupported_grant_type"}
```

**Relevant Express.JS code used for proxy routing:**

```
app.all('/proxy', function(req, res) {
    var url = req.header('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint');
    console.log(req.body); //prints all form data variables in JSON format
    console.log(res.body); //undefined

    request({url: url}).pipe(res).on('error', function(error){
        //I think I may need to pipe more information using request?
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**Request details using cURL:**

```
curl -v https://uniquename.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
 -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=3MVGxyzxyzxyzxyz"
-d "client_secret=99889988" -d "username=jfirst.last@email.com" -d "password=pswd"

> POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: uniquename.salesforce.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 207
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 207 out of 207 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 06:04:55 GMT
< Set-Cookie: BrowserId=auu1mgvHSMS1EedDEduz8Q;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Exp
ires=Sun, 27-Sep-2015 06:04:55 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
  "id":"https://test.salesforce.com/id/05390530530",
  "issued_at":"1438132525896197",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "instance_url":"https://uniquename.salesforce.com",
  "signature":"blahblah",
  "access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
* Connection #0 to
host uniquename.salesforce.com left intact
```

As you can see, I get back a valid response from the cURL request. I suspect something is wrong with the proxy, as it may not be forwarding all the form data to Salesforce, but I'm not sure how to debug that in Express.JS. The reason I suspect this is because if I try `curl https://uniquename.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` it returns the same `unsupported_grant_type` error.

Comment: Follow Up: I tried using the `request.post(url).form({key:'value'})` method, which is supposedly how you submit URL Encoded forms, but I still get a 400 response.

Comment: It looks like your proxy is not passing the content-type header through to the endpoint.

Comment: I tried `request({url: url, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})` but it's still not working...should I be passing it another way?

Comment: X-post here w/ bounty: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85349/getting-unsupported-grant-type-error-when-using-angular-js-app-expressjs-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working by switching to use the [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) proxy. I deploy my AngularJS app on port 8080, and the proxy on port 3001. My packages are managed using `npm` and `grunt`. Here is the code for the proxy:

```
var host = 'localhost';
var port = 3001;
var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer().listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('CORS proxy running on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

And here is how I'm making the HTTP request in AngularJS (you have to fill in your own credentials in the data object):

```
var login = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    data: 'grant_type=password&client_id='+encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_ID)+'&client_secret='+encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_SECRET)+'&username='+encodeURIComponent(EMAIL)+'&password='+encodeURIComponent(PASSWORD+USER_SECURITY_TOKEN),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }
};

$http(login).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
.error( function(response, status){
    console.log(response);
    console.log("Status: " + status);
});
```

You can run the proxy with the `node server.js` command, and run the AngularJS app with `grunt`. I hope this helps someone out, this was a tough problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're proxying everything in the HTTP request.  I've included some code below that will pass the request method and the request headers to your endpoint..  Also try using the 'request-debug' library so you can compare the proxy HTTP request vs your curl request and look for differences

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
require('request-debug')(request);

app.all('/proxy', function(req, res) {
    var url = req.header('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint');

    var options = {
        url: url,
        method: req.method,
        headers: req.headers
    }

    request(options).pipe(res).on('error', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            //TODO: do something useful with the response
        } else {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This method gives me HTTP error `405 (Method Not Allowed)`. Also, I'm not totally sure how to get the proxy's HTTP request. That's not the same as the `req` object, is it? If so, then I've posted those details in the OP.

Comment: I got past the original error, now I'm getting a response back from Salesforce:

`HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 21:58:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`    How do I enable POST??